# Find out my Windows 8 product key

Tags: windows, uefi, bios

I have had several problems trying to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows 8.1 so as it was booting in UEFI mode, as I'm not that into PC games, I decided to *format the hard drive and just install Ubuntu*. Now I find I need Windows, but I need **the product key** to download it **which is supposed to be in the BIOS**.

- How can I **find out my windows key from the BIOS?**
- As I will install Windows in some free space I reserved in the hard drive, is it going to erase my Ubuntu bootloader? Can I recover that later?

Comment: The Windows product key is not in the BIOS.  It's on a sticker on the bottom of your PC.

Comment: @Fabby: This changed in more recent versions of Windows. The 8 PC I bought a couple years back has no key on the holographic sticker, rather the OEM key is encoded in the BIOS. Another (ineffective) anti-piracy method by Microsoft.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat: O_o

Comment: I don't really see this a off-topic--the techniques are mostly Ubuntu-specific, and it's like extracting any other firmware or--though not shown here--Windows registry data. (Registry hives are just another part of the NTFS filesystem; accessing NTFS is generally considered on-topic. *Perhaps others disagree and I am not representing this as any kind of accepted policy*, but that's my view.) In any case, if this were reopened it could be made a duplicate of [Retrieve Windows 8 Product Key from mainboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233181/retrieve-windows-8-product-key-from-mainboard)

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo hexdump -s 56 -e '"MSDM key: " /29 "%s\n"'  /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

- From a comment by David6 on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment#comment1128031_638033)