# Can I recover my Windows product key from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

I am struggling right now with using ubuntu and would like some help.

So right now i'm running ubuntu from a USB flash drive after Windows 7 somehow left.

How can I get my windows product key which is somewhere on my laptop hard drive, from within Ubuntu?

Comment: Retrieving a Windows key has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You may ask at superuser.com

Comment: If this is a pre installed Windows, you can find the key on a sticker on the bottom, if it is a laptop or the back, if on a pc.

Comment: Thanks MichealBay, I will ask there too, but the problem is relevant to ubuntu since i am running ubuntu. and Mark Kirby the sticker got worn out !!

Comment: try `sudo cat  /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM`

Comment: Charles Green, it says "no such file or directory". thanks anyway!

Comment: I edited your question down alot, as it has been confirmed the below answer works. As this is a quite common issue and not many people seem to know a solution, I edited to make it as clear as possable, so as many people can find it as possable and get help.

Comment: [In my opinion it would be best to consider this on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654606/know-my-windows-8-product-key#comment1519003_654606). That's not established policy--I don't think we have one for this--just my view. This is basically the same as [Retrieve Windows 8 Product Key from mainboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233181/retrieve-windows-8-product-key-from-mainboard) The answers--reading firmware storage vs. the Windows registry--are different but the general problem is the same. I suggest we close one as a duplicate of the other and maybe ask a mod to merge answers.

Comment: @MichaelBay but retrieving a windows key from ubuntu is ;)

Comment: @EliahKagan I agree, consolodating all those answers under one clear question would be a good thing, take it to meta for voting, I would support the merge.

Comment: At least with my Windows 8.1 installation, this results in a key different from that produced by [this other solution](https://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First recover your Ubuntu with going to [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

---

This answer is not written by me but by [Thomas](https://superuser.com/users/114769/thomas) on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/897706/retrieve-decrypt-windows-7-product-key-from-linux), please vote there, if you vote here thanks

> There is a great tool available for Linux called chntpw. You can get
> it easily on Debian/Ubuntu via:
>
> `sudo apt install chntpw`
>
> To look into the relevant registry file mount the Windows disk and
> open it like so:
>
> `chntpw -e /path/to/windisk/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE`
>
> Now to get the decoded DigitalProductId enter this command:
>
> `dpi \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId`

A comment from below says

> The path to the relevant registry file is
> /path/to/windisk/Windows/System32/config/RegBack/SOFTWARE

Comment: Pretty cool!  Just tested this on my home system and the Comment from below was correct for my home system.  That one is running Windows 10.  I like this!  +1

Comment: It's important to check the case of the folder and file names. On my Windows 10 computer, the file didn't exist; I had to use uppercase `SOFTWARE` for the file name.

Comment: Wow. This is a brilliant feature of `chntpw`.

Comment: Sadly, I get `File is too small; got 0 bytes while expecting 72 or more` on a windows 10 disk.

Comment: Worked on Windows 7 partition, ubuntu 18.04. Would not work on read only mount. Had to remount rw. Capitalization in path was different `chntpw -e /media/sdb1/WINDOWS/system32/config/software`

Comment: file `Windows/system32/config/software` does not exist on my Windows10 1803

Comment: If you have problems reading the system32 folder, try making a copy and supplying the path to the copy to the chntpw.

Comment: Should be a space between 'Windows' and 'NT'. Don't know how to make poor markdown respect it.

Comment: The disk must be mounted as read/write: `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/<device> /mnt -o remove_hiberfile`

Comment: Worked Ubuntu 22.04 - Windows 10, thank you so much.

Answer (score 9):

So for anyone wondering how [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/953130/75060) actually works.

Essentially you'll have to grab the contents of the registry key

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId
```

This is a so called `REG_BINARY`. Meaning it's just a collection of bytes. You could dump them via `chntpw` or copy them by hand.

Let's see what we have to do with those bytes in order to get our product key with the help of some *pseudo code*.

Once you have those in an Array, you need to extract the subset of bytes that encode the product id. In particular: the range between 52 and (52 + 14). That gives you 15 bytes.

```
EncodedId = DigitalProductId.Range(52, 52+14)
```

This is still a bunch of bytes, that don't at all resemble the product key. So let us decode it.

For that you need the collection of all the characters a product key can be made of:

```
Characters = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
```

Yes this is not the whole alphabet. As it turns out a Windows product key doesn't use all of the alphanumerical symbols.

Now let's do the decoding. 
We'll need:

- A variable to hold the product key
- A loop over 0 to 24. For each character of our product key
- An inner loop over 0 to 14 (In reverse) For each byte in our encoded id
- Some bit fiddeling and arithmatic for the decoding process

---

```
ProductKey = ""
FOR i = 0 TO 24
    c = 0

    FOR j = 14 TO 0 STEP -1
        # Shift the current contents of c to the left by 1 byte 
        #  and xor it with the next byte of our id
        c = (c * 256) XOR EncodedId[j]

        # Put the result of the divison back into the array
        EncodedId[j] = FLOOR(c / 24)

        # Calculate remainder of c
        c = c MOD 24
    LOOP
    # Take character at position c and prepend it to the ProductKey
    ProductKey = Characters[c] + ProductKey
LOOP
```

Finally we insert the "-" character into the string at the appropriate places.

```
FOR i = 4 TO 1 STEP -1
    ProductKey = ProductKey.Insert(i * 5, "-")
LOOP
```

And we're done!

... Almost:

```
PRINT(ProductKey)
```

Now!

---

Capabilities of our *pseudo code*

- `$array.Range($from, $to)` Get the contents of `$array` from `$from` to `$to`
- `$array.Insert($where, $what)` Insert `$what` at `$where`
- `FOR $var = $start TO $stop [STEP $step]` loop the variable `$var` from `$start` to `$stop` applying `$step` on each iteration
- `$a XOR $b` Calculate **bit-wise** exclusive or on the numbers `$a` and `$b`
- `$a MOD $b` Calculate remainder of the division of `$a` and `$b`
- `$array[$i]` Take only the element at position `$i` from the array
- `#bla bla` Is a comment and will be ignored
- Strings are just char arrays.

---

You can see 3 actual implementations in C#, PowerShell and Python over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1247859/390654)

Comment: Alright, quick tip! Let’s say you want to get the Windows  license key from your machine and you’re running Linux. Simply open a terminal and run the following command.

sudo hexdump -s 56 -e '"MSDM key: " /29 "%s\n"' /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM

Comment: Is `/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM` only available for OEM licenses??